# How do I create a copy of my application without duplicating source code?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, build.gradle

I have been working on this problem all day. I have an application (inherited, not developed by myself) which has never really used build configurations properly.

Ideally I want three - Debug, Power User, Release.

Historically, when a release has been done, the developer just renames the version name to one of these three, changes any relevant connection strings and saves it somewhere and deploys out, overwriting the old application.

I've made some changes already by creating two build variants, and using these build variants to determine the connection strings for my application to either the live system or the test system (node API backend).

What I want to do is use the gradle to change the application id suffix so that if I am deploying dev, I can deploy it as a completely different application, with it's own version name and app label, without having to change these every time.

in terms of the setup for that I have already done this:

```
debug {
    manifestPlaceholders appLabel: 'DevApp'
    minifyEnabled false
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules-debug.txt'
    applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
    versionNameSuffix 'bvd'
}
```

But here this doesn't work as it doesn't match the package name in the manifest file. I get the message:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> No matching client found for package name 'com.baywater.app.debug'
```

Is there any way I can do this without creating an entirely separate package? and even then, if I create a new package, which links to the original source code would I need another manifest file?

Currently this is my folder structure, where everything is inside the app folder, including the appName class. I tried creating a new package within this, called debug, but it still didn't work because it's referencing the package name from the manifest file.

I have read somewhere that they apparently detached the appID from the package name, but it definitely doesn't seem that way from the things I have tried?

Thank you,
Craig

[image]

Comment: "But here this doesn't work" -- what does "doesn't work" mean? "as it doesn't match the package name in the manifest file" -- that is perfectly normal.

Comment: by it doesn't work I mean it doesn't build because of:
No matching client found for package name 'com.app.debug'
I understand that it's looking to match the package name, but I have seen things online which talk of changing the appID suffix independent of the package name, so I'm unsure of what steps I am missing.

Comment: I don't use the Google Services plugin for Gradle, which would appear to be what is giving you the error message. IIRC, it uses a JSON file for configuration. Did you update it for your application IDs?